# Split and concatenate dataframe

Tags: pandas

So i have dataframe which looks like this one:

```
>>>df = pd.DataFrame({
        'id': [i for i in range(5)],
        '1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        '2': ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'g']
        })
>>>df

    id  1   2
 0  0   a   f
 1  1   b   g
 2  2   c   h
 3  3   d   i
 4  4   e   g
```

I want to convert this dataframe to following dataframe

```
>>>df_concatenated
    id  val
1   0   a
1   1   b
1   2   c
1   3   d
1   4   e
2   0   f
2   1   g
2   2   h
2   3   i
2   4   g
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to pd.melt

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id'], value_vars=['1','2']).set_index('variable',append=True)
```

The other is by splitting by `.loc` accessor and concatenating. Long but it works

```
res1=df.iloc[:,[0,2]]
res1.columns=['id','val']
res=df.iloc[:,:2]
res.columns=['id','val']
res2=pd.concat([res1,res])
res2

 variable   id  value
    0   1   0   a
    1   1   1   b
    2   1   2   c
    3   1   3   d
    4   1   4   e
    5   2   0   f
    6   2   1   g
    7   2   2   h
    8   2   3   i
    9   2   4   g
```

Comment: thank you very much, works great with a little change
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id'], value_vars=['1','2']).set_index('variable').rename_axis(None)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df = df.rename({"1":"val"},axis=1)
df_temp = df[["id","2"]]
df_temp = df_temp.rename({"2":"val"},axis=1)
df.drop("2",axis=1,inplace=True)
out_df = pd.concat([df,df_temp],axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
print(out_df)
```

output:

```
    id  val
0   0   a
1   1   b
2   2   c
3   3   d
4   4   e
5   0   f
6   1   g
7   2   h
8   3   i
9   4   g
```